# Module not found error for nodejavabridge_bindings.node when executing jest test although file exists on specified directory

Tags: java, node.js, jestjs, node-modules

I am using NCache NodeJS client package and writing tests by calling NCache API's. Package has dependency of Java. After I installed and used that package to write simple test. Test execution failed with module not Found error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwJQI.png)
**Messgae:**
The specified module could not be found.
\\D:\GitHome\Test\node_modules\java\build\Release\nodejavabridge_bindings.node

```
  at Runtime._loadModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:893:29)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:21:16)
```

File in above mentioned directory exits.

**Note**: When I used that package in simple index.js file it worked fine as expected but unable to run with jest.

No major configuration done for jest in package.json file.
Java jdk-11.0.6 installed on box and JAVA_HOME is set.

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm7zp.png)

[test.specs.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW5Tx.png)

Unable to identify the exact reason of failure therefore stuck on how to resolve it.
**Environment:**
OS: Windows
node: 14.15.3
jest: 26.6.3

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-16.0.1\bin\server` needs to be in your path. On windows can `Edit the system environment` > `Environment Variables...` > `System variables` and add `C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-16.0.1\bin\server`

Other option is to add it to your test runner. For example in WebStorm edit the `Run Configurations` and add `Environment variables` `PATH=C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-16.0.1\bin\server`